# Confused about D3.js : SVGAnimatedLengthList is not a function error

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to make a bar plot object using D3.js but I can seem to get it to work.

I defined the x-scale like this:

```
    var Barplot = function(){
            this.x = d3.linear().....

    ...
```

And then I try to use the scale like this

```
    this.bar.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d){
             return this.x(d) + 5;
        }
```

However when I run this I get this error ->

```
    TypeError: SVGAnimatedLengthList is not a function (evaluating 'this.x(d)' ).
```

and i have no idea why especially since it will work if I change this.x to var x.

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to two different things. Inside the attribute function, `this` refers to the current DOM element (see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#attr)). If you really need to refer to the outer `this`, save it in a variable (e.g. `var that = this`) and then use `that`.